# Cycled images in linux/gtk program suddenly stop displaying

Tags: python, linux, gtk

I have an extremely simple application for a Raspberry Pi. (It's an educational kiosk for a children's museum if anyone cares.) In python, I have an infinite loop in a thread reading a line from a serial port. Based on the input, I display one of 14 different jpg images. I am not putting all the code here, but it's a very bare-bones GDK application. I have an Arduino feeding the serial port the information to cycle through all the images for debug purposes. In response to the input, I do the following:

```
self.CurrentImage.set_from_file("image.jpg")   # the name here is one of 14
```

Not to anyone's great surprise, this works. But as I let the Arduino hammer at the input, the screen would randomly show a white image and nothing again after. I checked the standard out window and the data was still coming and the images still being read. And when I say *random* I mean that at some point in the input-and-display process, it stops displaying. There are no errors being reported. Sometimes I might get 4-5 images in sequence before it dies, or I might make it through the list twice. It's simply not deterministic. My mind wandered to thinking maybe I'm not clearing first and having a memory leak. I made the following amendment:

```
self.CurrentImage.clear()
self.CurrentImage.set_from_file("image.jpg")
```

The problem persisted. I decided to scrap the method and go for something that didn't involve reloading images. At startup I created a separate GTK Image widget for each file. Then in response to the input data, I did this:

```
self.CurrentImage.hide()
self.CurrentImage = self.AlphaImage # or one of the other 13 Images I created
self.CurrentImage.show()
```

The nice thing about this method is that the image displays much faster. The first method had the screen briefly go white as the image was loaded. However, once again, after a random number of image switches, the window goes white. Diagnostic output shows that the loop is happily reading data and selecting images.

In the original version where I loaded images as needed, there was exactly one widget on the window. So it's not possible that another widget is covering it. The second version has an Image widget for each jpg file. If one is covering another, I should still at least see that image.

I'm good at thinking outside the box, but I admit that Linux is a weak area for me. Nothing is occurring to me to try to make this work. I'd whinge that I'm under time pressure here and children will be disappointed... but it was supposed to be done before Christmas and I only got the final art yesterday. That reminds me that there's one final note and the reason I thought my first method was failing: I created temporary graphics of my own that was one word of black text on a white background. Those images displayed without problem until the screensaver kicked in.

I'm open to any suggestion as to how to track this down and fix it.

Comment: So, in the second version, are you just adding one image on top of another in the window? Or are you removing the previous widget before adding the new image to the window?

Comment: Not removing, no. In my code above, You'll notice a call to hide() for the visible image, then a show() for the replacement.

Comment: Have you tried removing the image instead of hiding it? It would also help if you could provide a [example], but I'll try to reproduce this on my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I haven't tried removing it. I do know that both paradigms I tried DO work. They just fail after a time. Also, the Pi notified me that the OS had updates, so I installed those and restarted. I had a brief moment of hope that the problem was fixed because I cycled through the images more than twice. I had to step out of the room. When I returned, the screen had gone white again. The problem is still there. I'll see what I can do on making something reproducable.

Comment: I also just had update notifications :-). Do try removing the image; it works for my test code. You just call `remove(image)` for the parent widget of your image; in my code, the parent widget is called `window`, since it's an instance of `Gtk.Window`, so I call `window.remove(image)`. To add the new image to the window (and this works on several other widgets too, like `Gtk.Box` and `Gtk.Frame`) use `window.add(image)`. I did something similar to what you're doing; I made a list of images, and just iterate through the list and add the new image every 2 seconds.

Comment: I  haven't yet gotten back to the project, but my big concern is that the changes are happening inside a thread which changes the image on lines read from the serial port, and in turn that arrangement is the source of my troubles. I could put everything inside a timer (as you did) and if the issue goes away, then problem with being in a thread? serial port being weird? The one odd thing I didn't expect was that opening the serial port seems to reset the arduino. It should connect and just read the next lines coming out, but the arduino always seems to be at the start of sequence.

Comment: Yes, the Arduino resets every time you connect the port. This happened with me when I tried to use Python's built-in `open()` function to read the serial port. I recommend that you use the [`pyserial`](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) module, if you aren't already; it enables you to repeatedly read/write from/to the serial port without resetting the Arduino. Do you have your `Gtk` code in separate threads? If so, that could also be part of the problem; you should only have GUI code in the main thread.

Comment: That is likely a problem, then. (The Arduino reset isn't a problem. Frankly, in my situation that's desirable.) The GTK code that changes the image is in the thread that's reading the serial port. Is it not valid to change an image in a thread?

Comment: You shouldn't put the GUI in a thread, because it can cause memory-related issues, where the version of a widget in one thread gets changed, and is therefore different than the same widget in the other thread.

Comment: I don't think I have to use a thread to do everything. I might get away with it in somewhere else. Or is there another way to get a single widget to cycle images where I trigger that in a thread? I'm going to have to try what I can. Sadly, not quickly. I nearly died less than 24 hours ago. Thankfully I got to the hospital on time and relaxing today with my laptop and following up on this.

Comment: OK, I reviewed your comments. The problem isn't how I changed the images. Both methods I used were fine. It's that I was changing the images within the thread that was reading the serial port. Since I had a simple string, I used idle_add to pass the string to the Gtk library. That did the trick. There were no failures once I did that. It was a bugger to find information about doing that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sylvester, I figured this one out. The problem isn't how I was updating the images, it was *where* I was doing it. In the thread catching the serial input was *not* the place to do it. I reduced the thread to simply reading the line, then did the following:

```
GLib.idle_add( self.updateImage, lineInput )
```

then in the function `updateImage` I did the business logic of selecting the correct image and updating. Problem solved.

Comment: What is `lineInput`? Is it a function or a variable? Does it return something when there is data to be read from the serial port?

Comment: It's a single line read from the serial port. if you're curious, there's an RFID tag reader that kicks out a \r\n delimited line.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: You should accept your answer now.